# How to recreate a sentence from the positions of words in a sentence and list of unique words

Tags: arrays

I need help with this for school.

I have an array of unique `words = ['I', 'am']`

And the positions in which these words appear:
`["0","1","0","1"]`

This should be recreated as : "I am I am"

This is my code so far:

```
unique_words = ["I", "am"]
positions = [" 0", "1", " 0", "1"]
```

Sorry that's all I have, any help? I've tried a few things but none have worked. Cheers.

Comment: Just index them then. `print(unique_words[int(positions[0])])` assuming that the indices represented in positions are strings, and not integers.

Comment: Hi, I tried this method and all that was printed was "I".

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through your positions array and print out the value at the correct position in your unique_words array. An example using python syntax:

```
unique_words = ["I", "Am"]
positions = ["0", "1", "0", "1"]
outstring = ""
for position in positions:
    outstring += unique_words[int(position)] + " "
print(outstring)
```

Comment: Your code won't print `"I am I am"` but four lines with one word in each.

Comment: Now I'm getting the error "List indices must be integers or slices, not str".

Comment: I am assuming your positions are strings then. If that is the case you can make a conversion with int(). I updated the answer to reflect your input

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can go with:

```
print(" ".join(map(unique_words.__getitem__, map(int, position))))
```

This will replace every position by the corresponding word and then concatenate all the words into a string.

Comment: My mistake, this method worked for me and is more efficient than the one above! Thanks, I've been trying to solve this for hours.