# How to stop having duplicate words in the list when using a list of positions in python

Tags: python, list, position

I have code which saves all the words in the sentence to a text file and saves the list of positions in to another textfile.

Rather than saving all the words in to the list I'm trying to find a method so that it will only save each word once to avoid duplication.

Additionally for my list of positions it will see if the word appears more than once and if it does it saves it as the first position which appears in the word which is fine but then it skips a position e.g [1,2,3,2,5] rather than the last position be 5 it should be 4 as there's no position 4 if that makes sense.

I don't expect anyone to do this for me but is there a method I should be using e.g if word in sentence do x or using enumerate()?

Here is my code:

```
#SUBROUTINES
def saveItem():
    #save an item into a new file
    print("creating a text file with the write() method")
    textfile=open("positions.txt","w")
    textfile.write(positions)
    textfile.write("\n")
    textfile.close()
    print("The file has been added!")

#SUBROUTINES
def saveItem2():
    #save an item into a new file
    print("creating a text file with the write() method")
    textfile=open("words.txt","w")
    textfile.write(str(words))
    textfile.write("\n")
    textfile.close()
    print("The file has been added!")

#mainprogram

sentence = input("Write your sentence here ")
words = sentence.split()
positions = str([words.index(word) + 1 for word in words])
print (sentence)
print (positions)




#we have finished with the file now.
a=True
while a:
    print("what would you like to do?:\n\
    1.Save a list of words?\n\
    2.Save a list of positions?\n\
    3.quit?\n\:")
    z=int(input())

    if z == 1:
        saveItem()
    elif z==2:
        saveItem2()

    elif z ==3:
        print("Goodbye!!!")
        a=False        

    else:
        print("incorrect option")
```

Sample input sentence:
Programming is great Programming is so much fun

Sample list of words stored in text file:
['Programming','is','great','Programming','is','so','much','fun']

(the words are repeated)

Sample positions:
[1,2,3,1,2,6,7,8]

Instead I'd like the list to be stored like:
['Programming','is','great','so,'much','fun']

and the list of positions like:
[1,2,3,1,2,4,5,6]

Comment: Your description is confusing. Can you give us a sentence and the expected result/output as an example to work with? Also, is the file I/O stuff important or do you know how to do this?

Comment: I suppose you could use a set to store only unique words, but how are those words correlated with the positions in the other file then? I think it's better to save its word once with its respective positions in one file.

Comment: I've updated my question to hopefully make it more clear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303800/how-to-recreate-a-sentence-from-the-positions-of-words-in-a-sentence-and-list-of

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it but I think this should work:

```
from collections import Counter
sentence = raw_input(">>> ")

words, positions, d = [], [], {}
for i,word in enumerate(sentence.split(' ')):
    if word not in d.keys():
        d[word]=i
        words.append(word)
    positions.append(d[word])

# To further process the list
c, new_positions = Counter(positions), []
cnt = list(i for i in range(len(positions)+1) if not(i in c and c[i]>1))
new_positions = [p if c[p]>1 else cnt.pop(0) for p in positions]

# store the positions result
with open('positions.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(' '.join(map(str,new_positions)))

# store the words result
with open('words.txt','w') as w:
    w.write(' '.join(words))
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.py
>>> Programming is great Programming is so much fun
Words list:  ['Programming', 'is', 'great', 'so', 'much', 'fun']
Positions list:  [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 5, 6, 7]
New Positions list:  [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This works ok except for the fact that when you're trying to recreate the sentence the sample sentence is: programming is lots of fun i love programming and the output is:
{'programming': 0, 'is': 1, 'lots': 2, 'of': 3, 'fun': 4, 'i': 5, 'love': 6} As programming appears twice in the sentence shouldn't it have two positions otherwise the sentence couldn't be recreated probably?

Comment: On running your updated code it gives a name error that Counter is not defined .

Comment: @DaniM, yes you need to import `from collections import Counter`

Comment: Rather than outputting it, to save it in the text file I originally created do you just input new_positions and words into the subroutine saveItem() & as I'm using python 3 is raw_input the only difference which would be input in python 3 .

Comment: @DaniM, in python3.x `raw_input` is equal to `input()`, but yes the above code is also compatible with python3.x (except for raw_input and prints). Now to save the results there are many ways - depends on the form you want to save them as - I mean you want to save them as string, as list, as word per line etc...

Comment: Save as a list . However when I use my subroutine it says I must convert it to a string as I'm using the method of writing to a file .

Comment: @DaniM, yes writing as list is not that easy because it is not convenient to read back if you wish. So the one solution is to use `pickle` module and try to dump the list on the file - and the other solution which I would recommend would be to write your results as string - in file contents a list has no meaning. I will update the answer to show what I mean - also in this way it is also easy to read the list back from the file or even append new items in the future. It is also a good practice to use the keyword `with` when processing a file cause it handles many stuff automatically.